# R dataframe all the coocuring words columns facing the string - create coocurences - bigram - dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a Data Frame of this format:

```
df <- data.frame(names= c('perform data cleansing','information categorisation'))
                      names
1     perform data cleansing
2 information categorisation
```

And I would like to obtain this one with all the **coocurences**:

```
                        names           tokens1              tokens2
1      perform data cleansing           perform                 data
1      perform data cleansing              data            cleansing 
1      perform data cleansing         cleansing              perform
2  information categorisation       information       categorisation
```

Comment: Have you tried using `strsplit`?

Comment: Yes, my issue is more about the coocurence part

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(names= c('perform data cleansing','information categorisation'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#build list of words
words <- strsplit( df$names, " ", fixed = TRUE)
#find every combination of two words
combo <- lapply( words, combn, 2, simplify = FALSE )

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "perform" "data"   
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "perform"   "cleansing"
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# [1] "data"      "cleansing"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "information"    "categorisation"
```

Comment: Wimpel: suggested continuation: `df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(combo)),,drop=FALSE] ; cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(sapply( words, combn, 2, simplify = FALSE ), t)))`. Might need to guard against `factor`s, but it brings the new tokens back to the original frame, as expected in the OP. (It requires using `combo <- sapply(...)` instead of `lapply`, but from there use `combo` in my last part.)

Answer (score 1):

Given that it looks like you want a data frame output, the following will work. It will also account for strings with any number of bigrams.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(names2 = ifelse(str_count(names, "\\S+") > 2, paste(names, word(names, 1)), paste0(names))) %>%
  separate(names2, paste0('token', 1:max(str_count(.$names2, "\\S+"))), fill = "right") %>%
  gather(key, token1, -names) %>%
  arrange(names, key) %>%
  mutate(token2 = lead(token1)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  select(-key)

                       names      token1         token2
1 information categorisation information categorisation
5     perform data cleansing     perform           data
6     perform data cleansing        data      cleansing
7     perform data cleansing   cleansing        perform
```

Comment: Missing the third combo: `"perform"` and `"cleansing"`.

Comment: addressed circular bigrams

Comment: `information categorisation` is missing from the result

Comment: @dmca thanks a lot, there is still an extra line with a `FALSE` value.
Still helpful. I tried something inspired from your posts. Have a look.

Comment: You may be running different versions of the packages. I don't get any false values when running from a clean R session.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an answer, inspired by the previous ones.

```
df <- tibble(names= c('perform data cleansing','information categorisation'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

words <- strsplit( df$names, " ", fixed = TRUE)

mutate(df, name1=lapply(words, combn, 2, simplify=F)) %>%
    unnest(name1, .id='index') %>%
        ## separate list in double columns
        separate(col=name1, into=c('supp0', 'cooc1','cooc2', 'supp1')) %>% 
            ## reorder columns and suppress extra ones 
            select(index, names, cooc1, cooc2, -supp0, -supp1, -stringsAsFactors)
```

Where index indicates the `names` ' original index.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  index names                      cooc1       cooc2         
  <int> <chr>                      <chr>       <chr>         
1     1 perform data cleansing     perform     data          
2     1 perform data cleansing     perform     cleansing     
3     1 perform data cleansing     data        cleansing     
4     2 information categorisation information categorisation
```